# NSAttributedString and iPhone Deployment Target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I'm using **NSAttributedString** inside my app. Does that mean I have to set my iPhone **Deployment Target** to 6.0 because **NSAttributedString** is only supported starting from iOS 6.0?
EDIT: i'm using **NSAttributedString** like here http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-use-nsattributedstring-in-ios-6.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set deployment target lower than ios6 also but your `NSAttributedString` will only be working and effective on devices having `iOS6` and later. I would recommend you to go for iOS6 as majority of users have already upgraded to iOS6, somewhere I read the number is **84%** who have upgraded to iOS6, you can find the references for the [users adapting to iOS6](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57537774-37/ios-6-adoption-hits-61-percent-just-one-month-after-its-release/)

Comment: my application will not work correctly without the code that uses NSAttributedString

Comment: According to the documentation, `NSAttributedString` is iOS 3.2+. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: @JustSid But all of the useful methods that make use of `NSAttributedString` were added in 6.0.

Comment: @user836026 If your app requires `NSAttributedString` and all the useful `UIKit` methods that were added in iOS 6.0, then you must set your Deployment Target to 6.0. If you need to support iOS 5.x then you must have lots of runtime checks to work around the lack of those methods in 5.x.

Comment: majority of users have upgraded to iOS6 so I would recommend to go for iOS 6.